# passing special characters as arguments to subprocess in python (2.7.x)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to store the out put of mediainfo command in linux in a variable. I am using the subprocess module for this. The problem is that the arguments for mediainfo command have special characters. here is the snippet

the shell command is:

```
 mediainfo --Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%" test.mp4
```

and the python code is:

```
mediain = str('--Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"')
mediaout = subprocess.check_output("medainfo", mediain ,"test.mp4")
print mediaout
```

error im getting is

```
--Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
mediaout = subprocess.check_output("medainfo",     '--Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"',"test.mp4")
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
 process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 660, in __init__
raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

any help in this regardd is aprreciated, absolute newbie in python
Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: --Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
    mediaout = subprocess.check_output("medainfo", '--Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"',"test.mp4")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 568, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 660, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) expects the first argument to be a list. Try this:

```
args = ['mediainfo', '--Inform=Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%', 'test.mp4']
mediaout = subprocess.check_output(args)
print mediaout
```

Comment: get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 8, in <module>
    mediaout = subprocess.check_output(args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mediainfo', '--Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"', 'test.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: sorry.. the file was missing. Now its ignoring the arguments for some reason.
If i run the mediainfo command from shell i get 1.76 as output which is the aspect ratio of the video file. but when i run it through python subprocess module i get the complete output. which i get when run " mediainfo filename" command from shell

Comment: @user3589690: try removing the quotes from the parameter value (see the update).

Comment: did not understand:
do  you mean:
args = ["mediainfo", --Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%", "test.mp4"]

Comment: ok got it working. THe following works:

args = ["mediainfo", '--Inform=Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%', "test.mp4"]
thanks for your help eugene

Answer (score 0):

Possibly better to keep the command format in a string and pass it to `subprocess.check_out()` as list:

```
cmd = 'mediainfo --Inform=Video;%DisplayAspectRatio% test.mp4'
mediaout = subprocess.check_out(cmd.split()) #will split cmd over whitespaces and pass to check_out as a list.
print mediaout
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 11, in <module>
    mediaout = subprocess.check_output(cmd.split()) #will split cmd over whitespaces and pass to check_out as a list.
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mediainfo', '--Inform="Video;%DisplayAspectRatio%"', 'test.p4']' returned non-zero exit status 1